# Converting cell content to string data type in Excel using C#

Tags: c#

In the below code I am getting this kind of exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Data_Consistency.exe
>   Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

```
for (i = 0; i < excelCell.Columns.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (excelCell.Value2 == null)
        continue;
    else
        excelWorksheet.Range[excelCell,Type.Missing].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is

1. get value from cell:

   `var cellValue = (string)(excelWorksheet.Cells[10, 2] as Excel.Range).Value;`
2. write to cell again (already string)
   or write `=TEXT(var, "0")` which convert in excel

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.......
{

string l_connectionString = "";

```
                    string l_filePath = txtComparisonFile.Text;
                    string l_fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(l_filePath);
                    if (l_fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
                        l_connectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"; //for below excel 2007  
                    else
                        l_connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + l_filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';";
                    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    excelApp.Visible = false;
                    string workbookPath = l_filePath;
                    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
                            0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                            true, false, 0, true, false, false);
                    Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
                    string currentSheet = l_selectedSheet;
                    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);
                    Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(l_comparisonSheetRange);
                    excelWorksheet.Columns.NumberFormat = "@";
                    excelWorkbook.Save();
                    excelWorkbook.Close();
                    g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtCompare = g_objExcelHelper.GetDataTable(l_connectionString, l_selectedSheet, l_comparisonSheetRange, g_objExcelHelper.g_objDtCompare);
```